# SQLite And/or statement not working

Tags: sqlite

When I use the following command below:

```
select * 
from storm 
where (variable = "TMP" OR 
       variable = "VVEL" OR 
       variable = "UGRD" OR 
       variable = "VGRD" OR 
       variable = "RH" OR 
       variable = "HGT") AND level >=150 AND level <=200
```

The variable part parses out what I need from there, but the level command seems to be completely ignored. All levels are displayed with this command, but I only want those between 150 and 200.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: are You sure You used the parentheses in Your code? This should work. See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1f19b/1

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select * from storm where variable IN ('TMP', 'VVEL', 'UGRD', 'VGRD', 'RH', 'HGT') AND level BETWEEN 150 AND 200
```